# Dependency Analysis Warning - Skip Install is disabled

Tags: xcode, frameworks

When I archived my application I got this error for all my custom frameworks

> Warning: Installation Directory starts with '@executable_path' but
>   Skip Install is disabled.

I added my frameworks to my application my linking to them first and then creating a copy build false to the frameworks directory.

On each framework project I configured the Installation Directory to "@executable_path/../Frameworks" based on several tutorials I searched for on google. I believe this is to avoid installing the frameworks on the user's library (not sure).

Just to be clear, I want my frameworks to ship inside the application bundle, under the frameworks folder.

Now, I see a property named Skip Install on each of the frameworks projects build settings. Here is a description of what it means:

> SKIP_INSTALL Description  Activating this setting when deployment
>   locations are used causes the product to be built into an alternative
>   location instead of the install location. [SKIP_INSTALL]

When I activate this property the warning is gone, but can someone explain to me what this is? Because it implies that the @executable_path/../frameworks/ will be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

In XCode 6.3.1:

- Go to Build Settings, turn on 'All' not just 'Basic'
- In the 'Deployment' section, set 'Skip Install' to Yes.

This will fix the warning.  The thinking behind it is, if you're including the framework in your executable(s), then you don't want to install it separately

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but you have to set "Framework Search Paths" in Build Settings and remove Preprocessor Macros Debug value..

May you get help..